# Compiling Maven Project throws Error while using Custom Jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have generated a Jar file by doing the following options

Project 1:
i)Build the Project using Maven "clean compile package install" command

ii)Export->JAR File as ccfix.jar

Project 2:

iii)I have added the ccfix.jar through BuildPath->Add External Jars->ccfix.jar

iv)So Classes in Project2 reference to the classes in ccfix.jar and its referencing properly (as it doesn't show any compiler warnings or Errors)

v)But while Building the Project2 using Maven.I am getting the

```
COMPILATION ERROR :  error"package com.oracle.cloud.commerce " does not exist [i.e ccfix.jar contains the package com.oracle.cloud.commerce]
```

So I am not sure where the problem is -Either with Generating Jar's in Project1 or as i added the jar through Add Build Path instead of Maven and compiling it with Maven

ccfix.jar -pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.oracle.cloud.commerce</groupId>
    <artifactId>ccfix</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <argLine>-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http=DEBUG</argLine>
                       <!--  <argLine>-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true</argLine>-->

                    </configuration>
                 </plugin>
             </plugins>
         </pluginManagement>
     </build>

  </project>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jp</groupId>
    <artifactId>OCC</artifactId>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-for-MuleServer-3.7.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <munit.version>1.2.1</munit.version>
        <eclipsePluginVersion>2.8</eclipsePluginVersion>
        <jdkName>JavaSE-1.7</jdkName>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <junit.version>4.9</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.6,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>attach-test-resources</goal>
                                            <goal>filter-resources</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeMuleDependencies>false</excludeMuleDependencies>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                    <!-- <outputDirectory>deployable</outputDirectory>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${mule.version.notes}-${mule.version}</finalName> -->
                <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-support</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-spring-support</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    </inclusions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${eclipsePluginVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- by default download all sources when generating project files -->
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.mule.MuleServer</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-config</argument>
                        <argument>src/main/app/mule-config.xml</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-deployable</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>deployable</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>target</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.zip</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${munit.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <coverage>
                        <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                        <formats>
                            <format>html</format>
                        </formats>
                    </coverage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/munit</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
    <!-- plugins for creating site reports -->
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>http://mulesoft.org/download/attachments/92/checkstyle.xml?version=1
                    </configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>${jdk.version}</targetJdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <links>
                        <link>http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api</link>
                        <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api</link>
                        <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api</link>
                    </links>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-beta-2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mule.transports/mule-transport-email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-email</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-client</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-management</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-sxc</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mockobjects</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockobjects-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.09</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.devkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-devkit-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.18</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
            <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
            <version>1.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-support</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-spring-support</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>       
    </repositories>

    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Need your two maven files. Sounds like your ccfix.jar does not contain the dependencies for `com.oracle.cloud.commerce` which would normally happen if you don't use a Maven build for adding external jars.

Comment: Normally, if you were to do this, you'd have your ccfix.jar include its dependencies as well.

Comment: @Compass I have attached the pom.xml for ccfix,jar(Project1) and for Project2

Comment: Your ccfix jar needs the following to include dependencies with itself https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Just the first bit, add jar-with-dependencie s for maven-assembly-plugin, and use the jar it creates.

Comment: Seems like you're using some sort of IDE (`BuildPath->Add External Jars->ccfix.jar` - is this a menu path?) If so, what IDE is that? Usually, adding jars in your IDE does not affect Maven build.

Comment: @Arkadiy Yes this option is available in with Eclipse IDE.Right Click Project->BuildPath->Configure Build Path->Select Libraries Option->Add External Jar.I too believe that Adding External Jar's won't affect Maven Jars

Comment: @Compass Do you want me to create the Jar as an Executable Jar or Need to add the Dependencies present in pom (ccfix.jar) to Assembly plugins

Comment: @Compass I have build the Jar using Maven build Generation ,but didn't compile/Run my Jar File Project.Whether do you think will there be any error there ?

Comment: Adding files through Eclipse's build path runs counter to how Maven works. You should be able to assemble the second jar entirely through Maven without Eclipse's involvement.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**:From Project1 i created a Jar

**Step 2**:I created a Local Maven Repository using the following command from Command Prompt

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\vmanohar\Desktop\ccfix-1.4.5.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle.cloud.commerce -DartifactId=ccstore -Dversion=1.4.5 -Dpackaging=jar

**Step 3**:Then i added that Dependency in Project2,

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.cloud.commerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>ccfix</artifactId> 
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now the Jar is Properly Referenced in Project2.

Answer (score 0):

Maven does not (easily) allow you to modify the build path.

You need to run "mvn install" in the first project to install the artifact and then list the artifact as a dependency in the pom.xml for the second project.

Comment: I am currently using the following command to Generate the Jar " clean compile package install " in Eclipse.

Comment: That installs it in the local maven repository.  So you just need to add the dependency in your second project.